# Recovered File's Filename

Tags: encoding, filenames, arabic, persian, data-recovery

Hi I recently recovered my site's files after a server crash.
I had a wordpress site with too many uploaded image files with Persian/Arabic file-names.
The problem is the file names are renamed after the recovery.
The names are so weird. I can't identify a specific encoding so that I can revert the original names. It does look like Hex, but it isn't! Can you help me?

Here's an example recovered file name:

> #U06a9#U0627#U0646#U06a9#U0633-#U0633#U0627#U0646#U062f#U0648#U06cc#U0686-#U067e#U0646#U0644-150x103.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name looks like id's of Unicode character. Let's look at the first character.

**U06a9**

- U: Unicode character.
- 06a9: Id of character (hexadecimal.)

In this format the letter a would be U0061

Here is a python script to convert that name to the original.

```
import sys

obf = sys.argv[1]

name = obf.split("-")[0]

recovered = ""

working = ""

for c in name:

    if c == 'U':

        working = "\u"

        continue

    working += c

    if len(working) == 6:

            recovered += working.decode("unicode-escape")

print recovered + obf.split(".")[len(obf.split(".")) - 1]
```

Example usage:

```
python recover.py U06a9#U0627#U0646#U06a9#U0633-#U0633#U0627#U0646#U062f#U0648#U06cc#U0686-#U067e#U0646#U0644-150x103.jpg
```

Note input can not start with a hash.

Comment: Thank you. That's it! Now I have to find a way to mass rename them. Let's try some apps.

Comment: You should be able to use this python program I created plus a bash script to mass fix them.